# append to .csv file with pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a treatment that uses pandas.DataFrame.to_csv() to create .csv files of my data and I wish to execute this treatment several times, each time appending new data to the already existing file. (column names of the output are the same for each treatment)

Of course, an idea to work around my problem would be to create a file for each treatment and then concatenate them, but I would like to do that without changing much to my scripts.

Is it possible to append to an existing .csv file in pandas 0.14 ? (unfortunately, I cannot upgrade my version).
I was thinking I could do something using the 'mode' argument, http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.14.0/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html?highlight=to_csv#pandas.DataFrame.to_csv , but I do not seem to find the right thing to do.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can use write mode `'a'`. You may also need/want to use `header=False`.

I'm a little unclear why you don't want to do `.read_csv()` into `df.append()` into `df.to_csv()`, but that seems like an option too

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer, your solution works as needed. I had also thought of reading and appending, as you suggested, but my data is quite voluminus, so I guess that performance wise, the best is to follow your first suggestion.

Comment: If your data is big-ish, maybe you would benefit from using a database (or something)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. My data actually is in a database, and so are the results of my treatment, but I cannot add a new table (server admin constraints) - and I do not want to alter already existing results (I am testing performance of a new software version - and still need the treatment results of the old software version). So there you have it, :)

Comment: Makes perfect sense @MatinaG